# The confusing base address between kernel32.dll and kernelbase.dll

Tags: windows, kernel32

It is said that on the offset 0x1C of `struct PEB_LDR_DATA` stores the head pointer to `In InitializationOrderModuleList`, is that right?

Beyond that, the second node of `In InitializationOrderModuleList` should be `kernel32.dll`, however, when I locate the second node, it turns out not to be the base address of `kernel32.dll`, instead, it is something like `kernelbase.dll`, how can that be explained?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're relying on undocumented implementation details, and you ran into a newer implementation.

Implementation details aren't guaranteed to remain unchanged.

This particular detail appears to have been changed to provide defense-in-depth against code injection attacks using buffer overflow bugs.

Comment: Specifically, how can I write an assembly code to locate the base address of `kernel32.dll`? This problem has puzzled me for days...

Comment: @RichardMorning: Same way you do in C code: Pass the string `"kernel32.dll"` to `GetModuleHandleA`, from any process on the same system.  Performing injection remotely is no longer easy, intentionally.  That's the whole point of ASLR.

Comment: Thanks. But I am trying to insert a piece of code into an overflowed buffer... If I use the disassembled C code, it would bring too many overheads, plus the buffer is not big enough...

Comment: @RichardMorning: I hope you are not surprised that modern OS features designed to prevent buffer overflows from allowing arbitrary code execution do, in fact, make it much more difficult to use a buffer overflow for arbitrary code execution.

Comment: I made an attempt just now and failed again... The following is my assembly code: `xor edx,edx` `mov ebx,fs:[0x18]` `mov ebx,[ebx+0x30]` `mov ecx,[ebx+0x0c]` `mov ecx,[ecx+0x1c]` `mov ecx,[ecx]` `mov ebx,[ecx+0x08]` `mov dword ptr[address],ebx`. It is supposed to find TEB and then PEB, then `struct PEB_LDR_DATA`, then `InInitializationOrderModuleList`, and _kernel32.dll_ should be the second of the list. However this piece of code found _kernelbase.dll_ again... This is frustrating...

Answer (score 0):

The comments here are correct, you're running into new-ish (actually pretty old at this point) changes to Windows that dynamically load kernel32.dll.  The strategy you're attempting stopped working after Vista.

That doesn't mean you can't, of course.  This tactic works for me just fine:

http://blog.harmonysecurity.com/2009_06_01_archive.html